# How make expanded and stretched layout box with Fyne

Tags: go, fyne

I want expanded and stretched box for layouting widgets, so that my application looks like this: 
[image]

I.e. top and middle box both lengthy in both direction.

I tried use this code with Box(because I didn't found any "free" layouting in the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/fyne.io/fyne@v1.2.3/layout?tab=doc)):

```
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
)

func main() {
    f := app.New()
    w := f.NewWindow("")
    label1 := widget.NewLabel("Label1")

    b1 := widget.NewButton("Button1", func() {})
    b2 := widget.NewButton("Button2", func() {})
    label2 := widget.NewLabel("Label3")

    w.SetContent(
        fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(
            layout.NewVBoxLayout(),
            fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewVBoxLayout(), label1),
            fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewHBoxLayout(), layout.NewSpacer(), b1, b2, layout.NewSpacer()),
            label2),
    )

    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

But it's definitely not the same thing:

[image]

Does fyne support such layouting and how to do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Like this? Or describe more details.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
)

func main() {
    f := app.New()
    w := f.NewWindow("")
    label1 := widget.NewLabel("Label1")

    b1 := widget.NewButton("Button1", func() {})
    b2 := widget.NewButton("Button2", func() {})
    label2 := widget.NewLabel("Label3")

    w.SetContent(
        fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(
            layout.NewVBoxLayout(),
            fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewHBoxLayout(), layout.NewSpacer(), label1, layout.NewSpacer()),
            layout.NewSpacer(),
            fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewHBoxLayout(), layout.NewSpacer(), b1, b2, layout.NewSpacer()),
            layout.NewSpacer(),
            fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewHBoxLayout(), layout.NewSpacer(), label2, layout.NewSpacer()),
        ),
    )

    w.Resize(fyne.Size{Height: 320, Width: 480})

    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

---

EDIT: tried `NewBorderLayout` but not sure if this is what you want.

Do not forget to tell me the right way when you get it. Good luck!

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "fyne.io/fyne"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
)

func main() {
    f := app.New()
    w := f.NewWindow("")
    label1 := widget.NewLabel("Label1")

    b1 := widget.NewButton("Button1", func() { fmt.Println("button1") })
    b1.ExtendBaseWidget(b1)

    b2 := widget.NewButton("Button2", func() { fmt.Println("button2") })
    b2.ExtendBaseWidget(b2)

    label2 := widget.NewLabel("Label3")

    labox1 := fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewGridLayoutWithRows(3),
        fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(
            layout.NewCenterLayout(),
            label1,
        ))

    labox2 := fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewCenterLayout(), label2)

    w.SetContent(
        fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(
            layout.NewBorderLayout(
                labox1,
                labox2,
                nil,
                nil,
            ),
            labox1,
            labox2,
            fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(
                layout.NewAdaptiveGridLayout(2),
                b1,
                b2,
            ),
        ),
    )

    w.Resize(fyne.Size{Height: 320, Width: 480})

    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

[image]

Comment: yep, it fits, but only for cases where widget is minimized. For example if I need to fill button on all red rectangle on my screen.

Comment: I've finished with this - https://pastebin.com/uxxevU21 so combination of BorderLayout and Grids it's what I was looking for.

Comment: You don't need the CenterLayout here (as labels will center themselves by default). Also you don't need the ExtendBaseWidget, that is only needed if you are defining your own widgets.

Answer (score 2):

If you want central content to expand I would recommend using the BorderLayout, the Box widget is designed to pack items in rather than stretch them out. VBox will expand width and use the minSize of elements for their height (to create an even list) and HBox would expand height whilst keeping items at their minimum width (like a button bar).

For packing a whole application UI it is more likely that you want to use a container directly, such as `fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewBorderLayout(...), ...)`.
You may find the layout section of the [Fyne Tour](https://tour.fyne.io/) helpful, specifically [BorderLayout](https://tour.fyne.io/layout/borderlayout.html).

Comment: Yes, but if the content is not central? I used to write GUI application only with wxWidgets where layouting usually provided by sizers. And base sizer ([wxBoxSizer](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_sizer.html#overview_sizer_box)) is sizer that allow growing in both directions (height and width). So I wonder why fyne doesn't contain such possibility?

Comment: Fyne tour is indeed helpful it seems you added many from time I've last checked it.

Comment: Fyne is designed differently - layouts control the size and position of items in a container. Widgets do not have weights or hints to influence their size.

Comment: All sorts of layouts are possible, your question illustrated centred so that’s why the answers only showed that option. BorderLayout may be what you want if you’re trying to attach to an edge of a container

Comment: My question was about container with elements that growing in both directions. Your answer (as far I understand) - that fyne use totally different layouting mechanism so for every possible combination there is special option. 
And my concrete example is just one small container in bottom (i.e. status bar) and split the rest area/space on two equal part. That's the point. Central widget not more important than widget above. Other answer is showing two of them so I got the idea ;-)

Comment: I guess the main difference is to consider a heirarchy of containers and layouts. You could combine BorderLayout with a GridLayout to get the central space split in two. We feel that this approach is easier to maintain because you don't have to do the maths of weights and alignments.